# Extract info from a list in R

Tags: r, list, benford.analysis

I need to extract specific information from a list in R. My data is 'Benford' object and doesn't seem to be coercible using `as_tibble()`

My data looks as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(benford.analysis)

# read data
data = read.csv("https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/counties/totals/co-est2019-alldata.csv", header = T)

# ONLY SELECT THE NUMERIC COLUMN
x <- data %>% 
  select(CENSUS2010POP)

# SPLIT THE DATA INTO TWO GROUPS
x$CITY <- "CITY_A"
x[1500:3193,2] <- "CITY_B"

# SPLIT THE DATA ON THE CITY VARIABLE
dat_list <- split(x,x$CITY)

# APPLY THE BENFORD ANALYSIS TO THE NUMERICAL VALUES PER GROUP
output <- map(dat_list, ~benford(number.of.digits = 1, discrete = TRUE, sign = "positive", data = .x$CENSUS2010POP))
```

I wish to create a data frame with the `CITY` name i.e. `CITY_A` in one column and the `$ MAD.conformity` in another for each element in the list.

Any help on how I can pull these elements from my list and store them in a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map_dfr()` to extract `MAD.conformity` on each iteration, row-bind the results, and add an `.id` column containing the names of each element of `dat_list`. Since `dat_list` was created by `split`ting on `CITY`, the names already correspond to the levels of `CITY`. (I'm not familiar with the structure of `Benford` objects, so you may have to tweak the `$MAD.conformity` index.)

```
output <- map_dfr(
  dat_list,
  ~ benford(
      number.of.digits = 1, 
      discrete = TRUE, 
      sign = "positive", 
      data = .x$CENSUS2010POP
    )$MAD.conformity,
  .id = "CITY"
)
```